# Loop through a list using puppeteer and click a button

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to use puppeteer to:

- create an array from an `ul` list
- Loop through the list and click a button.
- Each button click opens a modal. Within the modal, another button has to be clicked.
- Delay the next loop before continuing.

I've tried to do this a number of ways using `page.evaluate` and my array always seems to be empty. Can someone please show me what I'm doing wrong here.

```
<ul>
  <li><button>Connect</button></li>
  <li><button>Wait</button></li>
  <li><button>Connect</button></li>
  <li><button>Connect</button></li>
</ul>
```

Path: `puppeteer.js`

```
const buttons = await page.evaluate(() =>
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("ul > li button"))
);

for (let button of buttons) {
  if (button.innerText === "Connect") {
    button.click();
    document
      .querySelector(
        "div.artdeco-modal"
      )
      .click();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`page.evaluate`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) cannot return DOM nodes, as it can only return serializable data. This is data that can be wrapped `JSON.stringify` to transfer it from the browser environment to Node.js

Instead, you need to use [`page.$$`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#pageselector-1) to get a list of DOM elements. As you are also only looking for buttons with a specific text, I would recommend to use [`page.$x`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#pagexexpression) which runs an XPath query and can also filter depending on the text of the button.

**Code Sample**

```js
const buttons = await page.$x("//ul/li//button[contains(text(), 'Connect')]");
for (let button of buttons) {
    await button.click();
    const modal = await page.$('div.artdeco-modal');
    await model.click();
}
```

The above code, first queries all buttons with the text "Connect" on the page and iterates through them. It clicks each button and after each click queries for the model dialog and clicks it.

Comment: page.$x returns an empty array. When I try to use `document.evaluate("//ul/li//button[contains(text(), 'Connect')]", document)` in console it return `Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.`

Comment: @bp123 Can you try this: `page.$x("button[contains(text(), 'Connect')]");`

Comment: That didn't work. I ended up getting it to work with `await page.$x("//button[contains(., 'Connect')]");`

Comment: @bp123 I guess the HTML looked a bit different then. Glad you got it working.